# Using overloaded VB.NET Not operator from C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, operator-overloading

I have a VB class which overloads the `Not` operator; this doesn't seem to be usable from C# applications.

```vb
Public Shared Operator Not(item As MyClass) As Boolean
    Return False
End Operator
```

I can use this in VB.NET:

```vb
If Not MyClassInstance Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

I am trying to us this in a C# application but it won't build.

```
if (!MyClassInstance) 
{ 
     // do something
}
```

I get the error

> Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'MyClass'

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: try writing the class name with parameter braces because you have to call that function that's returning a boolean value. i.e
`if(!MyClassInstance()) 
{ 
     // do something
}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Not` operator in VB.NET is a *bitwise* operator, it produces the one's complement of its operand.  It doesn't have the equivalent of C#'s `!` operator, a logical operator.  You must use the equivalent bitwise operator in C# to use your VB.NET operator overload:

```
if(~MyClassInstance) 
{ 
     // do something
}
```

You can write a function in VB.NET that will map to the C# logical operator.  That needs to look like this:

```vb
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SpecialName> _
Public Shared Function op_LogicalNot(item As MyClass) As Boolean
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, unfortunately if I use the op_LogicalNot I am not allowed to also use the VB Not operator, so I can have it strange in VB or strange in C#.

I will just stick to using the bitwise operator in C#.

Comment: Fascinating, Visual studio complains that a method with the same name is declared twice, but it does build and run.

Cheers.